# how can i pass a variable to a class and call that variable in any other screen without it being reset

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to be able to call an empty variable from a class, assign a value to it and make it persistent, anything aside provider e.t.c would be help, i don't want to overhaul the entire app again to do some bloc, provider e.t.c

NB: all screens are stateful widgets

i have tried creating a class with an empty string and passing a value to it from another screen, but this doesn't seem to work

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class MethodA {

//  id(user, context){
//    var name =user.email;
//  }
 String identity;

 MethodA({this.iD});

  bool isLoggedIn() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> addUserA( userinfo) async {
    //this.iD=id;

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .document('furtherinfo').collection(identity).document('Personal Info')
        .setData(userdoc)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

each time i pass the argument to i.e  foo='bar';

and i import that class in another screen, i.e screen 9, foo is automatically set to null, but i would want foo to be bar

Comment: Why not use something like a Provider?

Comment: Tried provider, but I kept getting could not find the correct provider<string>above widget abc, there are about 14 different screens, one attached to the root and the others spread out, when I used provider, it was in a particular screen, say screen 4a, and I called it in 5b

Comment: I find the Provider easier to use than most state management tools. Are you looking to keep track of the logged in user from Firebase?

Comment: It seems for provider to work the screen has to be a child of another screen or the provider has to be in the root, but the variable  is created in a screen different from the root and the provider called on another screen further apart

Comment: Provider just needs to be above the widgets that are going to use it, dont you want this?

Comment: @TinusJackson registering and getting the uid, which would be used in a class that contains futures that writes to firestore with the uid

Comment: @TinusJackson like I said I know that now, I can overhaul the entire thing, so that they would lineup, only the first two screens are in line the rest are pushed routes, the data originates in one of the routes therefore, I don't see how provider would work since they aren't stacked together

Comment: Meant I can't overhaul

Comment: Added my answer, which does not require to overhaul the entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the Provider since it is the easiest way for me to manage state throughout the app. Flutter starts with one component on top of the widget tree so i would place my provider here.

Example

```
void main() {runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, // Provider to manage user throughout the app.
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.green,
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          accentColor: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your class you can do the following

```
class MethodAService with ChangeNotifier {
 String _identity = null;
 FirebaseUser _user = null;

 // constructor with the (new changes )
 MethodAService(FirebaseUser user){
      this._user  = user;
 }

  get identity => _identity ;

  setIdentity(String identity) {
    _identity = identity ;
    notifyListeners(); // required to notify the widgets of your change
  }
}
```

Then when you want to use it anywhere in your app just do the following in the build method

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); // to get the current user
    final methodA = Provider.of<MethodAService>(context); // get your service with identity

   // now you can set the string using 
    methodA.setIdentity('new identity');

    // or just use it like this
    if(methodA.identity.isNotEmpty()){
      print(methodA.identity);
    }else{
       print('Identity is empty');
     }

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MethodAService>(
            builder: (context) => MethodAService(user), // Your provider to manage your object, sending the Firebase user in


   child: loggedIn ? HomePage() : LoginPage(), );
  }
```

References

[Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

[Fireship 185 Provider](https://github.com/fireship-io/185-advanced-flutter-firestore)

[Great Youtube video explaining the code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFxk_KJCqgk)

**Update for comment**

For getting the user uid you can just do `user.uid`

Changed code above to fit the

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am in the process of implementing this, i would give a feedback, however, does final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); return the UID, and can i use it in  within the MethodA class seeing that i already have some functions that write to firestore within that class

Comment: Changed code to fit requirement, mostly moved the MethodA provider down and adding a constructor to take the FirebaseUser, then in your class you can do what you want with it.

Comment: the constructor skewd by code, all .dart files with an insatance of the class turned red, constructor asking for parameter user.       Is it possible i just pass classmethodA.indentity=user.uid, in the registration page, and use the class function i had in the class to write to firestore with the Identity gotten

Comment: @rizu Why do instantiate in all of your code? you should only need to instantiate once in the top level.

Comment: what i mean is that i have had an instance of class MethodA, in all pages/screen that write to firestore, MethodA class has e.g 3 methods, each responsible for writing to various sections of firestore.    what in need in essence is when the user registers, i want to UID to be passed to class MethodA, then as i goes through each screen, upon completion of registration, the data(maps) is passed to class MethodA which now writes the maps for each section with is UID as document reference

Comment: i have done all of this except being able to hold the UID within a variable in class MethodsA throughout the lifecycle of the app, i have already implemented the provider in the application root, all i need now is for it to be updated in the registration screen and held **presistently** in the class MethodsA, that just what i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure put the whole app in a StreamProvider is the best choice. That means the app will be rebuilt on each stream value.

To make a Widget available on all screens, you need a **[TransitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionBuilder.html) in your MaterialApp**.

To avoid the external dependency you can also use an [InheritedWidget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=8&t=0s)

**signed_user.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignedUser extends InheritedWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;

  SignedUser({@required this.user, @required Widget child})
      : super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(SignedUser oldWidget) => true;

  static SignedUser of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(SignedUser);
}
```

**my_transition_builder.dart**

```
class MyTransitionBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const MyTransitionBuilder({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTransitionBuilderState createState() => _MyTransitionBuilderState();
}

class _MyTransitionBuilderState extends State<MyTransitionBuilder> {
  StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser> _builder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _builder = StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return SignedUser(
            child: widget.child,
            user: snapshot.data,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _builder;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // this will make your inherited widget available on all screens of your app
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MyTransitionBuilder(child: child);
      },
      routes: {
        '/editAccount': (context) => new EditAccountPage(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**usage in edit_account_page.dart**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = SignedUser.of(context).user;

    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: Firestore.instance.document('users/${user.uid}').get(),
```

Comment: Your first comment is correct, but for this the user will not sign in and out every second, also provides better user control throughout the app

Comment: @TinusJackson you are right, the builder is not called frequently, but what is the benefit of the Provider 'above' the MaterialApp and why do you prefer this and not the TransitionBuilder? If Flutter has an integrated solution for this, I think it's the better choice

Comment: Please how can i get the value of     `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, // Provider to manage user throughout the app.
        ),
      ],` in a class not a widget, thank you

Comment: @AlexanderKwint I am still also new to Flutter and dart, what i struggled with and the solutions that worked for me is what i recommend. I am open to better implementations, i will try the TransitionBuilder (have not used it before). Thanks